# exception jdbc error tried all solutions so far

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

I have this error jdbc : I tried so far (build path, jar folder into /bin/ folder and 2 others ) but still nothing

**You may say it's duplicate** (but I tried all the solution I saw so far 4 and i still have the same error" [image]

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

This is the code I am using :

```
import java.sql.*;
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {

    String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lorann?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    String uName = "root";
    String uPass= "";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    Connection co = DriverManager.getConnection(host,uName,uPass);
    Statement stmt = co.createStatement();


    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT contenu FROM niveau");
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    ResultSetMetaData rsm = rs.getMetaData();



    while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("contenu"));
    }

}}
```

Comment: did you read this? [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484764/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-eclipse)

Comment: Yes , i did if you see in the first lines (Build path) as tested solution

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution :** 
instead of using this :

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

we use :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

but i am not sure it's the solution because the expected console print : is not showing off

[ClassNotFoundException with com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver, MySQL Connector and IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286426/classnotfoundexception-with-com-mysql-cj-jdbc-driver-mysql-connector-and-intell?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)