# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer'

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend

Using springboot, I am trying to create a new table containing all products that get rated by users. It seems like there's something wrong with my datasource.driver. (I don't know) I have tried looking some solutions to the following error, but couldn't find any. I will greatly appreciate anyone who can answer my question.

Error in the console:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
at com.fsse2207.project_backend.ProjectBackendApplication.main(ProjectBackendApplication.java:9) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:171) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:123) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=(hidden)
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=(hidden)
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (Here is where things turn red. Probably where the error occurs)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken%40system.gserviceaccount.com
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.fsse2207'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.0.0'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-java:21.0.0'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

ProjectBakendApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProjectBackendApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectBackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

ProductApi:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class ProductApi {
    private ProductService productService;
    private ProductsRatedByUserService productsRatedByUserService;
    @Autowired
    public ProductApi(ProductService productService, ProductsRatedByUserService productsRatedByUserService){
        this.productService=productService;
        this.productsRatedByUserService=productsRatedByUserService;
    }
    @PatchMapping("/product/rating/{pid}/{numOfStars}")
    public ProductsRatedByUserResponseDto recordLikes(@PathVariable("pid") Integer pid, @PathVariable Integer numOfStars, JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken) throws ProductFoundByIdException {
        FirebaseUserData firebaseUserData=new FirebaseUserData(jwtAuthenticationToken);
        ProductsRatedByUserDetail productsRatedByUserDetail=productsRatedByUserService.updateProductRating(pid,numOfStars,firebaseUserData);
        return new ProductsRatedByUserResponseDto(productsRatedByUserDetail);
    }
}
```

productsRatedByUserServiceImpl:

```
@Service
@Component
public class ProductsRatedByUserServiceImpl implements ProductsRatedByUserService {
    public ProductsRatedByUserRepository productsRatedByUserRepository;
    public ProductRepository productRepository;
    public UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ProductsRatedByUserServiceImpl(ProductsRatedByUserRepository productsRatedByUserRepository,ProductRepository productRepository,UserRepository userRepository){
        this.productsRatedByUserRepository=productsRatedByUserRepository;
        this.productRepository=productRepository;
        this.userRepository=userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductsRatedByUserDetail updateProductRating(Integer pid, Integer numOfStars, FirebaseUserData firebaseUserData) throws ProductFoundByIdException {
        if(!productRepository.existsById(pid)){
            throw new ProductFoundByIdException();
        }
        UserEntity userEntity=userRepository.findUserEntityByEmail(firebaseUserData.getEmail());
        ProductEntity productEntity =productRepository.findById(pid).orElse(null);
        if(!productsRatedByUserRepository.existsByProduct(productEntity)){
            ProductsRatedByUserEntity productsRatedByUserEntity=new ProductsRatedByUserEntity(userEntity, productEntity, numOfStars);
            ProductsRatedByUserEntity productsRatedByUserEntityReturned=productsRatedByUserRepository.save(productsRatedByUserEntity);
            return new ProductsRatedByUserDetail(productsRatedByUserEntityReturned);
        }else{
            ProductsRatedByUserEntity productsRatedByUserEntity=productsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(productEntity);
            productsRatedByUserEntity.setTotalNumOfUsersWhoRated(productsRatedByUserEntity.getTotalNumOfUsersWhoRated()+numOfStars);
            productsRatedByUserEntity.setTotalNumOfUsersWhoRated(productsRatedByUserEntity.getTotalNumOfUsersWhoRated()+1);
            productsRatedByUserEntity.setAverageStars(BigDecimal.valueOf(productsRatedByUserEntity.getTotalStars()).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(productsRatedByUserEntity.getTotalNumOfUsersWhoRated())));
            return new ProductsRatedByUserDetail(productsRatedByUserRepository.save(productsRatedByUserEntity));
        }
    }
}
```

productsRatedByUserService:

```
public interface ProductsRatedByUserService {
    ProductsRatedByUserDetail updateProductRating(Integer pid, Integer numOfStars, FirebaseUserData firebaseUserData) throws ProductFoundByIdException;

}
```

Comment: This pretty much means that your app can not connect to DB, Check if you can connect via DB client using same exact credentials in that file, Also check if DB has some security and you should be whitelisted to be able to connect

Comment: I know almost nothing about spring-boot, but the error that he cannot find the driver's class is giving away the problem. You need to add the MySQL JDBC driver to your pom.xml.

Comment: @maio290 could be right check https://stackoverflow.com/a/50782269/1460591

Comment: @Youans When I didn't create all the layers for productsRatedByUser, everything worked fine. Does that mean it's related to database security? But I am using Amazon RDS and there's nothing that I need to do about its security?

Comment: @Youans I'm using Gradle rather than Maven so doesn't the same solution work for me?

Comment: @BenChu https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.31 - there's also a syntax for gradle there. The driver however is missing for sure. How you add it (application server, deployment file) is up to you.

Comment: Can you sho build.gradle file

Comment: @Youans I have shown the build.gradle file

Comment: Try replacing `runtimeOnly mysql...` line with `implementation 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.0.31'`

Comment: @Youans The problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update. For some reason, after running the build configuration, I downloaded a ton of files and the dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer error is gone. What I now get is another set of errors, which are solved thanks to @Andy Wilkinson

[running the build configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMlHg.png)

New set of errors while the previous one disappeared:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-11-22 02:01:43.352 ERROR 42740 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productApi' defined in file [/Users/chuben/Desktop/Coding_Projects/project_backend/build/classes/java/main/com/fsse2207/project_backend/api/ProductApi.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productsRatedByUserServiceImpl' defined in file [/Users/chuben/Desktop/Coding_Projects/project_backend/build/classes/java/main/com/fsse2207/project_backend/service/impl/ProductsRatedByUserServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productsRatedByUserRepository' defined in com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.products_rated_by_user.entity.ProductsRatedByUserEntity com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.product.entity.ProductEntity); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.products_rated_by_user.entity.ProductsRatedByUserEntity com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.product.entity.ProductEntity)! At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.products_rated_by_user.entity.ProductsRatedByUserEntity com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.product.entity.ProductEntity)! At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at com.fsse2207.project_backend.ProjectBackendApplication.main(ProjectBackendApplication.java:11) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productsRatedByUserServiceImpl' defined in file [/Users/chuben/Desktop/Coding_Projects/project_backend/build/classes/java/main/com/fsse2207/project_backend/service/impl/ProductsRatedByUserServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productsRatedByUserRepository' defined in com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.products_rated_by_user.entity.ProductsRatedByUserEntity com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.product.entity.ProductEntity); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.products_rated_by_user.entity.ProductsRatedByUserEntity com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.product.entity.ProductEntity)! At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.products_rated_by_user.entity.ProductsRatedByUserEntity com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.product.entity.ProductEntity)! At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productsRatedByUserRepository' defined in com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.products_rated_by_user.entity.ProductsRatedByUserEntity com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.product.entity.ProductEntity); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.products_rated_by_user.entity.ProductsRatedByUserEntity com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.product.entity.ProductEntity)! At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.products_rated_by_user.entity.ProductsRatedByUserEntity com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.product.entity.ProductEntity)! At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.products_rated_by_user.entity.ProductsRatedByUserEntity com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.product.entity.ProductEntity); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.products_rated_by_user.entity.ProductsRatedByUserEntity com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.product.entity.ProductEntity)! At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.products_rated_by_user.entity.ProductsRatedByUserEntity com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.product.entity.ProductEntity)! At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:107) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1061) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:365) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.products_rated_by_user.entity.ProductsRatedByUserEntity com.fsse2207.project_backend.repository.ProductsRatedByUserRepository.findTopByOrderByProductDesc(com.fsse2207.project_backend.data.product.entity.ProductEntity)! At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:119) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:259) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:103) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:139) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetterFactory$CriteriaQueryParameterSetterFactory.create(QueryParameterSetterFactory.java:298) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createQueryParameterSetter(ParameterBinderFactory.java:140) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createSetters(ParameterBinderFactory.java:129) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createSetters(ParameterBinderFactory.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createCriteriaBinder(ParameterBinderFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.getBinder(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:328) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:218) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:348) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You should post this new error as a new question. There's a problem with the `findTopByOrderByProductDesc` method on `ProductsRatedByUserRepository`.